# tools to 'draw out' your program instead of coding it out?

Tags: programming-languages

I have been thinking that are there any tools which makes coding like drawing?
if not, is it possible that we can drawing programs instead of coding them(debugging a program would like seeing an animation)?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read up about [Visual programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_programming_language).

Two languages, which both are mainly used for education purposes, are NXT-G for the [Lego Mindstorm NXT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms_NXT) and [EToys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etoys_%28programming_language%29). Another language, [vvvv](http://vvvv.org/), is widely used for rapid prototyping and development for "large media environments with physical interfaces".

Answer (score 0):

There is (commercial) software that is able to execute UML or BPL models, read more here: http://e2ebridge.com/